# Prevent double curly brace notation from displaying momentarily before angular.js compiles/interpolates document

Tags: angularjs

It seems to be primarily an issue in IE when there is a number of images/scripts to load, there can be a good amount of time where the literal `{{stringExpression}}` in the markup are displayed, then disappear once angular is done with it's compilation/interpolation of the document.

Is there a common reason why this would happen which would indicate I'm doing something generally wrong, or is there a known way to prevent this?

Comment: This could help: http://branchandbound.net/blog/web/2013/08/some-angularjs-pitfalls/

Comment: The above was the right solution

Answer (score 284, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the `ngCloak` directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

From the documentation:

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
>   the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.
>
> The directive can be applied to the `<body>` element, but the preferred usage is to apply multiple `ngCloak` 
>   directives to small portions of the page to permit progressive rendering of the browser view

Comment: To avoid the raw Angular HTML code, is `ngCloak` widespread/best practice? It seems like a no brainer, but I'm not experienced in AngularJS.

Comment: I don't think this will work if you load all scripts at the end of the body.

Comment: It won't. I wonder if there's another way to do it? Perhaps a way to detect when all controllers have loaded?

Comment: Aaah, wait, nvm, LOAS's answer is the solution if you load scripts last. Use the .ng-cloak class.

Comment: Load angularjs script at the `<head>` section of your html for `ngCloak` to be effective.

Comment: I can confirm it works perfectly if I load `angular.js` in the `<head>` section of my page.

Comment: If you're using latest angular version (+1.5) adding ng-cloak will be enough.

Answer (score 199):

Also, you can use `<span ng-bind="hello"></span>` instead of `{{hello}}`.

http://jsfiddle.net/4LhN9/34/

Comment: One feature about ng-bind that is sometimes overlooked is that you can specify text to display while Angular is loading: <span ng-bind="myScopeProperty">loading...</span>.  "loading..." will appear, then be replaced once myScopeProperty is defined.

Comment: @MarkRajcok: thanks for the tip!  I had no idea.  That's very simple and elegant and solves a problem I myself have had.

Comment: If you need multiple expressions, use ngBindTemplate.
E.g., <span ng-bind-template="{{scopeProperty1}} {{scopeProperty2}}">loading...</span>

Comment: You can also do {{hello || 'loading...'}}

Comment: @AndyJoslin Nice. With this approach, the angular js script needs to be in the head, as opposed to the bottom of the page, to avoid the {{}} expression from flashing when the page loads.

Comment: using ng-bind fixed it for me http://branchandbound.net/blog/web/2013/08/some-angularjs-pitfalls/

Comment: {{hello || 'loading...'}} is bad idea. Because if you want to show some some elements bound with flag in ng-controller that all elements will show and the ui will be a mess. The only solution is ng-cloak. You do not need css in the latest angularjs version.

Comment: Also binding is not a good idea in case you have large code, then you will need to update all those from {{}} to ng-bind

Comment: This i believe is the real answer!

Comment: I thank you a ton! This is helpful for me since I am trying to use Angular Page with backend consisting of Django only, and Django takes such {{ ... }} angular elements as its own, which messes up everything.

Answer (score 51):

To improve the effectiveness of class='ng-cloak' approach when scripts are loaded last, make sure the following css is loaded in the head of the document:

```
.ng-cloak { display:none; }
```

Comment: Adding !important is not bad idea also.

Comment: Wouldn't `visibility: hidden` be better?

Comment: @eomeroff, but `!important` is a CSS **hack** (bad thing) to promote a style to be selected, right? It breaks the CSS selector rules.

Comment: IMHO this is one of the cases !important was introduced for.

Comment: @Mark I would guess that "visibility: hidden" would still render the space needed for the template markup, whereas "display:none" doesn't render anything at all. With only the visibility hidden, any outer elements may suddenly collapse to the true inner size, instead of growing to size from nothing. I suppose it's whatever one prefers. :)

Comment: @JamesWilkins: Yeah..you're right. I might not have been thinking about the size difference when I wrote that.

Comment: visibility vs display is just a matter of preference. Try them both!

Comment: @JamesWilkins visibility: hidden or display: none are both good options, and depends on the goal -- if the goal is to preserve the document's structure then visibility:hidden works well, otherwise display:none does the trick.

Comment: @MJWunderlich : As I stated, "it's whatever one prefers.", so you're just rewording what I said. :P  ;)

Comment: @JamesWilkins I reworded & expanded to clarify.

Comment: @MJWunderlich : for who, me? (since you tagged my name) lol. ;) IMHO I think I was nore detailed and clear, but to each his own I guess. :P

Answer (score 40):

Just add the cloaking CSS to the head of the page or to one of your CSS files:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak, .ng-hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Then you can use the [ngCloak directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) according to normal Angular practice, and it will work even before Angular itself is loaded.

This is exactly what Angular does: the code at the end of angular.js adds the above CSS rules to the head of the page.

Comment: +1 I came up with the `[ngcloak]` selector myself, but this is more complete.

Comment: Awesome answer!  I load Angular at the end of my body, so ngCloak isn't available and it still flashes the {{}}.  This fixed it.

Answer (score 21):

In your css add folllowing

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
 }
```

And then in you code you can add ng-cloak directive.
For example,

```
<div ng-cloak>
   Welcome {{data.name}}
</div>
```

Thats it!

Answer (score 6):

You also can use `ng-attr-src="{{variable}}"` instead of `src="{{variable}}"` and the attribute will only be generated once the compiler compiled the templates. This is mentioned here in the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @pkozlowski.opensource answer, but ng-clock class did't work for me for using with ng-repeat. so I would like to recommend you to use class for simple delimiter expression like {{name}} and ngCloak directive for ng-repeat.

```
<div class="ng-cloak">{{name}}<div>
```

and

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-cloak>{{item.name}}<li>
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing me the mistake