# Angular Default Value if Binding is Null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've seen a similar question and followed it to a tee. [Angular Template Default Value if Binding Null / Undefined (With Filter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523076/angular-template-default-value-if-binding-null-undefined-with-filter)

My object looks like this:

```
{
  "image": {
    "icon_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/square_avatar/9/93770/2496414-dying-light-2013523175751_8.jpg",
    "medium_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_medium/9/93770/2496414-dying-light-2013523175751_8.jpg",
    "screen_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/screen_medium/9/93770/2496414-dying-light-2013523175751_8.jpg",
    "small_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_small/9/93770/2496414-dying-light-2013523175751_8.jpg",
    "super_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_large/9/93770/2496414-dying-light-2013523175751_8.jpg",
    "thumb_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_avatar/9/93770/2496414-dying-light-2013523175751_8.jpg",
    "tiny_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/square_mini/9/93770/2496414-dying-light-2013523175751_8.jpg"
  },
  "name": "Dying Light",
  "original_game_rating": null,
  "original_release_date": null,
  "objectID": "346569380"
}
```

I'm wrapping the left-hand side expression in brackets, but it doesn't display "TBA" for items that have a year of `null`.

```
<span>{{ (getDate(hit.original_release_date) | date:'yyyy') || 'TBA' }}</span>
```

I have a feeling, it's because I'm referencing a function and already using a set of parentheses. How can I solve this problem...?

Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Here's the `getDate()` function:

```
$scope.getDate = function(date) {
  return $filter('dateToISO')(date);
};
```

And the `dateToISO` filter:

```
.filter('dateToISO', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var dateTime = input.split(" ");
    var date = dateTime[0];
    var datePartials = date.split("-");
    var time = dateTime[1];
    var timePartials = time.split(":");
    var formattedDate = new Date();
    formattedDate.setFullYear(datePartials[0]);
    formattedDate.setMonth(datePartials[1]-1);
    formattedDate.setDate(datePartials[2]);
    formattedDate.setHours(timePartials[0]);
    formattedDate.setMinutes(timePartials[1]);
    return formattedDate;
  };
})
```

Comment: AngularJS version? Can you show the `getDate` function?

Comment: @tasseKATT Updated the question with the `getDate` function. Using Angular 1.2.8.

Comment: Can't replicate it so far. Can you show the custom `dateToISO` filter too?

Comment: Are you sure, that `null` returned? May be it's string `'null'` ?

Comment: Implement `default` filter also. and use it as `...|date:'yyyy'|default:'TBA'`

Comment: It's in the db as `null`, not a string. But it's printing to the page as "undefined".

Comment: @vp_arth I get an error and the page doesn't load properly if I do `... || default:'TBA'`.

Comment: You are missed `Implement` part of my comment :)

Answer (score 6):

Implement default filter also.

```
app.filter('default', [function(){
  return function(value, def) {
    return value || def;
  };
}]);
```

And use it as:

```
<span>{{getDate(hit.original_release_date) | date:'yyyy' | default: 'TBA'}}</span>
```

**Update:**
also your `dateToISO` filter may fails, if `undefined` or `null` been received.
Check its input.

```
.filter('dateToISO', function() {
  return function(input) {
    if (!input || !input.match(/^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}$/)) return;
    var dateTime = input.split(" ");
    var date = dateTime[0];
    var datePartials = date.split("-");
    var time = dateTime[1];
    var timePartials = time.split(":");
    var formattedDate = new Date();
    formattedDate.setFullYear(datePartials[0]);
    formattedDate.setMonth(datePartials[1]-1);
    formattedDate.setDate(datePartials[2]);
    formattedDate.setHours(timePartials[0]);
    formattedDate.setMinutes(timePartials[1]);
    return formattedDate;
  };
})
```

**Add:**

And in angular, you always have to do:

```
<span ng-if="hit.original_release_date">{{getDate(hit.original_release_date) | date:'yyyy'}}</span>
<span ng-if="!hit.original_release_date">TBA</span>
```

Comment: Still returning as "undefined". Weird. Is there not a way to separate the right-side expression and use a function on the left-hand side?

Comment: where is your `date` filter?

Comment: It comes after my module. `angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngSanitize' ]).filter('dateToISO', function() {...`.

Comment: no `dateToISO`, `date`. which gives you `yyyy`... Anyway, see simple way to solve your issue in bottom of answer.

Comment: Ahh, I guess that's an alternative way to do it. I guess that would work, but would also like to find out why I can't do a lh rh expression with a function.

Comment: I think, issue in your `.filter('date',`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
{{hit.original_release_date ? (hit.original_release date | date:'yyyy') : 'TBA'}}
```

Comment: It's printing to the page as "undefined".