# Show a value or another depending on if it's present

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following array:

```
vm.persons = [{id:1, name:'Manuel1', age:30}, {id:2, name:'Manuel2', errorCode:'Error', age:18}]
```

And I want to show in this way:

```
------------------
|Name    | Age   |
------------------
|Manuel2 | Error |
------------------
|Manuel1 | 30    |
------------------
```

So, if `errorCode` is present, the age should not be shown.

This is what I have right now:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-class="...">
      <td>{{::person.name}}</td>
      <td>{{::person.age}}</td>
    </tr>
```

How can I do that check. I'd like to show in first place the persons with error and then the rest. I think that you can do that with array.sort, right?

Comment: Use ng-show ng-hide 
read this https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-ngshow-and-nghide

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490652/angular-default-value-if-binding-is-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in persons | orderBy:'errorCode'" ng-class="...">
  <td>{{::person.name}}</td>
  <td>{{::(!person.errorCode) ? person.age : 'Error'}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you! Excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish that using directive [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-class="...">
  <td>{{::person.name}}</td>
  <td ng-if="person.age">{{::person.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

ng-if evaluate an expression, if true then shows the element... you could do something like `ng-if="person.errorCode != 'Error'"` or `ng-if="!person.errorCode"` you have to check for a true false expression that fit your needs...

Answer (score 0):

`<tr ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-class="...">
      <td>{{::person.name}}</td>
      <td>{{person.age == 'Error' ? '-' : ::person.age}}</td>
    </tr>`

You need to show some text if you dont want to show age else your design will run if it does not finds a

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the ?: ternary operator which acts as a simple if/then-like expression. This evaluates the first term (before the ?). If it evaluates to true, the expression after the ? is returned. If it evaluates to false, the expression after the : is returned.

So `{{::(person.errorCode ? person.errorCode : person.age)}}` should work, tho I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

use ng-if to print or not the col and colspan for prevent empty space

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-class="...">
    <td colspan="{{!person.errorCode ? '1' : '2'}}">{{::person.name}}</td>
    <td ng-if="!person.errorCode" >{{::person.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
 <tr ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-class="...">
      <td>{{person.name}}</td>
      <td ng-if="!person.errorCode">{{person.age}}</td>
      <td ng-if="person.errorCode">{{person.errorCode}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in order to make it work

```
  <tr ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-class="...">
  <td>{{person.name}}</td>
  <td>{{person.errorcode==""?person.age:person.errorcode}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

For ordering take a look at [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

You could define a custom function returning `1` if the element is defined and `0` if not.

Conditional display is already explained in multiple answers.