# Displaying "{{foo}}" string, instead of the content

Tags: angularjs

Here a sample of my code:

```
<ul> <li>{{model}} : Auris, Auris TS, Yaris</li> </ul>
```

Right now it displays nothing because there's no data for `{{model}}` and I would like to display the string "{{model}}" instead of the content.

Is it possible ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523076/angular-template-default-value-if-binding-null-undefined-with-filter

Comment: how about more information ? maybe a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Does a fiddle is really usefull ?

Comment: Not sure if he wants a directive or template, there is some difference. but I think @alex anwser should be sufficient. You could also just go with HTML special characters     <p>
        Lorem ipsum &#123; &#123; model  &#125; &#125;
    </p>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
<code ng-non-bindable>{{model}}</code>
```