# Default value of input textbox in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind, angularjs-ng-value

How do I set the default value of an input textbox in AngularJS so that it can be altered later? I wish to be able to submit the changed value of the textbox(using ng-model) to the server. Would using ng-value to set the initial value of the textbox be the correct approach in this case?

Comment: you could take use of `ng-init` directive simply

Comment: or see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30471421/3711660 - it will work even if user enters text, and deletes it - default value will be inserted

Comment: @pankajparkar Do you mean something like this <input ng-init="default-value" ng-model="final-value"> where the value entered by the user will be  accessible as final-value?

Comment: @NipunParasrampuria what do you mean by this?

Comment: Lets say the web page's HTML contains an element like the following: <input ng-init="default-value" ng-model="final-value">, where default-value is the value that I wish the textbox contain when the page is loaded. If the user later alters the textbox so that it contains a value other than the default-value, would I be able to access that value using $scope.final-value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the `ngModel` value:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myInput" />

$scope.myInput = "Default";
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply :). I had thought of that, but would I be able to access the updated value of that field using $scope.myInput when I wish to submit data to the server

Comment: @NipunParasrampuria -- Yeah, `$scope.myInput` will reflect whatever you put in that `input`