# Show a placeholder if value is null in html table using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have table that is populating a list using angularjs controller. How can I show a place holder(say a dash sign) if the place expression is null or undefined??

Here is a snippet.

[image]

I am populating the view as:

```
<td>{{trans.Status}}</td>
<td>{{trans.PaymentId}}</td>
<td>{{trans.TransId}}</td>
```

I found about `ng-show` in angular docs. But I really don't want to use an extra span under `td` as this

`<span class="empty" ng-show="!trans.TransId">N/A</span>`

Is there any better way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular Template Default Value if Binding Null / Undefined (With Filter)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523076/angular-template-default-value-if-binding-null-undefined-with-filter)

Comment: I think your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523076/angular-template-default-value-if-binding-null-undefined-with-filter

Comment: Might it be a good idea to give your fields a default value? Or is that impossible dud to further design of the Javascript?

Comment: <td>{{trans.TransId || 'N/A'}}</td>

Comment: Thanks @TomPietrosanti those answers what I were looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<td>{{trans.Status}}</td>
<td>{{trans.PaymentId}}</td>
<td>{{trans.TransId || 'N\A'}}</td>
```