# How to manage views with AngularJs and Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I am starting to use AngularJs on a rails app. And I wanted to know how to manage communication between rails and angularjs. I wanted to generate templates with rails and then angularjs will execute controllers to update view :

```
.span6.box.applications{ "ng-controller" => "ApplicationListCtrl"}
      .padding5.clearfix
        .clearfix
          %h2.inline.pull-left.no-border= t('home.titles.applications')
        .content.top5
          - if @applications.count > 0
            %table.table.table-striped
              %thead
                %tr
                  %th= Application.human_attribute_name(:id)
                  %th= Application.human_attribute_name(:name)
                  %th

              %tbody
                %tr{ "ng-repeat" => "application in applications" }
                  / %div{ "ng-include" => "", "src" => "'/applications/new.html'" }
                  %td {{application.name}}
                  %td {{application.name}}
                  %td{ width: "50px"}
                    .pull-right
                      - if can? :edit, Application
                        %span.fui-gear{"data-toggle" => "tooltip", :title => t('form.settings'), "ng-click" => "edit()" }

                      - if can? :read, Application
                        %span.fui-search.left10{"data-toggle" => "tooltip", :title => t('form.show'), "ng-click" => "show()"}
```

The problem is that I have a bad visual effect. It first displays me this :

[image: Application controller before angular execution]

then it will change it for :

[image: Applications with angularjs]

It works but I have the visual effect. How can I manage that. How can I create module reusable with AngularJs ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent double curly brace notation from displaying momentarily before angular.js compiles/interpolates document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866447/prevent-double-curly-brace-notation-from-displaying-momentarily-before-angular-j)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Rails or its template engine, but I do know that for angularjs to hide those template variables in their raw state while loading, you can try two things:

1. Try adding the `ng-cloak` attribute to the enclosing element (`tr` in this case) AND put `display: none !important;` in your CSS.
2. For a non-CSS solution, try using `ngBind` and `ngBindTemplate` instead of wrapping your template variables in curly brackets.

For example:

```
    <td ng-bind="application.name"></td>
```

I'll take a wild guess at the Rails template form for your example:

```
    %td{ "ng-bind" => application.name }
```

For more info, see the [AngularJS documentation on ng-bind](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBind).