# Angular shows double-brackets {{}} before page loads completely

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Before my webpage is completely loaded, all the brackets ({{}}) that I use to bind data with Angular is showing all over the page. Here's how some cells in my table looks before it's completely loaded:

[image]

So my question is if there's any way to prevent this from showing? It looks hideous.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010012/hide-angular-brackets-until-javascript-loaded

Comment: Use `ng-cloak` on elements that contain the `{{ expression }}` notation