# AngularJS dynamic page title keeps loading curly brackets first

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
<title ng-show="pageName">{{ $root.pageName }} - Domain Name</title>
```

I'm trying to change the page title dynamically, when the page is loading the title preloads `{{ $root.pageName }} - Domain Name` instead of being `- Domain Name` then loading `$rootScope.pageName` when its rendered.

Is there a way to hide `{{ $root.pageName }}` from being shown on page load till the application picks up the variable?

Comment: Have you tried ng-cloak? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866447/prevent-double-curly-brace-notation-from-displaying-momentarily-before-angular-j

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<title ng-bind="$root.title + ' - Your site'">Your site</title>
```

Note that in this case the title is on the `$rootScope`.

EDIT: Just tested and it looks like the dash keeps showing, however this should prevent it:

```
<title ng-bind="$root.title ? $root.title + ' - Your site' : 'Your site' }]}">Your site</title>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use ng-cloak directive to hide raw (uncompiled) form data.i think it will help you.

```
<title ng-cloak>{{ $root.pageName }} - Domain Name</title>
```

The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading.

see [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) link for detail.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ng-show` in title doesn't make sense. You could do something like:

`<title ng-bind="'MyApp - ' + $root.title">MyApp - Welcome</title>`

```
$routeProvider.when('/product', {templateUrl: '/partials/product.html',  controller: 'ProductCtrl', title: 'Discover our Product'}).when('/about', {templateUrl: '/partials/about.html', controller: 'AboutCtrl', title: 'About US'});
```

on your run(), add a $rootScope.$on:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(currentRoute, previousRoute){
//Change page title, based on Route information
$rootScope.title = $route.current.title;});
```

Read the Full source: https://coderwall.com/p/vcfo4q

Answer (score -3):

Yes it is possible.

Do something like this

```
<title ng-show="pageName">
    <span ng-model="pageName"></span>
    <span> - Domain Name</span>
</title>
```

Comment: -1: `ng-show` generally influences the `display` style of an element (animations aside) and `<title>` shouldn't contain anything other than text according to the [W3C style guide](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/TITLE.html).