# Angular JS first tutorial

Tags: angularjs

I have just started to learn Angular JS. I have a query regarding below code.

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
</head>
</body>
<h1>{{hello}} </h1>
<input type="text" ng-model="hello"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Query:** This piece of code is working fine but when I refresh the page I see {{hello}} for a fraction of second. why?

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249768/angularjs-ng-cloak-ng-show-elements-blink .Use ng-cloak to when your data is ready in scope.

Comment: Because Angular hasn't had a chance to replace the value. One strategy would be to hide a page/div until the data is ready (ng-hide/ng-show)

Comment: use ng-cloak in directive. put ng-cloak inside body tag.

Comment: this code *may* work, but it's already exhibiting a few style problems.  first, using `ng-app` without an assignment isn't recommended.  Secondly, you should consider loading Angular in the `<head>` element so that it can be available as soon as possible, rather than at the bottom.

Comment: moving angular script at start of body or head solved the problem

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/angularjs-why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body ng-cloak>
<h1>{{hello}}</h1> 
--------
--------
--------
--------

</body>
```

To prevent Angular html template from being displayed by the browser use ngCloak.

**Note:** Use ngCloak in your body tag that will help you hide these thing on complete page.

The best way to avaid this error is, use ng-bing directive see the example below.

```
<h1 ng-bind="hello"></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

**why does it happen?**

Your browser will render the HTML, and angular will be just a bit later with it's DOM manipulation

**solution 1: ng-bind**

You can use `<h1 ng-bind="hello"></h1>` to fill your H1 tag.
Because there is no HTML inside the H1 tag to render, you will not see it flash with the {{hello}} notation when angular hasn't done it's magic yet.

I think the downside for this is that you always need to have a wrapping element around the content you want to show.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

**solution 2: ng-cloak**

You can use ng-cloak to wrap anything you want to hide as long as angular is not ready.

It would look like:
`<h1 ng-cloak>{{ 'hello' }}</h1>` or `<h1 class="ng-cloak">{{ 'hello' }}</h1>` in your case.

The benefit I see in ng-cloak is that you can use it to wrap around a larger area.
You could use ng-cloak to hide your whole angular-affected area, and display a loader animation while angular is not up and running.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Just remember to add the `style` for [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) in your `head` otherwise it won't work as you expect as the style would need to be included by Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this:

```
<h1>{{hello}} </h1>
```

to this:

```
<h1 ng-bind="hello"></h1>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/30sae715/)

This happens because HTML is compiled at a later stage. So first you see the HTML, and then builds the angular effect.

If you set binding by adding attribute `ng-bind`, then you don't have brackets in the HTML code and brackets will not appear for a fraction of second.

If you want to know more about this, please read this: [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866447/prevent-double-curly-brace-notation-from-displaying-momentarily-before-angular-j)

Comment: this done not solve the problem. after this change even h1 is not getting updated when I type into input.

Answer (score -2):

Use **ng-cloak** directive.

```
<h1 data-ng-cloak>{{hello}} </h1>
```

The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading