# AngularJS: show loader image until data is loaded

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

[screen image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0RGa.png)

[screen image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1UBN.png)

displaying results using angular js + php, how to show loader image until data is loaded, here my code is written below,

How do I have AngularJS show a loading image until the data has finished loading?

app.js file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp3', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.filter('startFrom', function() {

    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
app.controller('customersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $http.get('http://www.testurl.com/index.php/site/getprofileLocations').success(function(data){

        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 20; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
    });
    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() { 
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```

and php code is here

```
<html ng-app="myApp3" ng-app lang="en">


<div ng-controller="customersCrtl">
<div class="content" >

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">PageSize:
            <select ng-model="entryLimit" class="form-control">
                <option>5</option>
                <option>10</option>
                <option>20</option>
                <option>50</option>
                <option>100</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">Filter:
            <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="filter()" placeholder="Filter" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5>Filtered {{ filtered.length }} Of {{ totalItems}} Total Locations</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <th>Id&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('id');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>
            <th>Place Name&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('name');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>
            <th>Category ID&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('category_name');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>


            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
                   <td>{{data.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.category_name}}</td>



                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems == 0">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h4>No Locations found</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">    
            <div pagination="" page="currentPage" on-select-page="setPage(page)" boundary-links="true" total-items="filteredItems" items-per-page="entryLimit" class="pagination-small" previous-text="&laquo;" next-text="&raquo;"></div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/angular/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/angular/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/angular/app/app.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

display loader onload and hide it once data loaded.

```
$scope.showLoader = true;
$http.get('http://www.testurl.com/index.php/site/getprofileLocations').success(function(data){
    $scope.showLoader = false;
    // rest of your code
});
```

EDIT: html code from Saeed's answer

```
<div ng-show="showLoader"><!-- so this div containing img will be dislpayed only when the showLoader is equal to true-->
    <img src="source"> <!-- or any other spinner -->
</div>
```

Comment: sir i alredy did, images attached above question, pls see above images

Comment: what i want is, when display the loader , screen 1 image display code part did not show.

Comment: use [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12866739/1398867 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17906446/1398867

Comment: @sairam : could you create a jsfiddle & replicate your issue there, htpp://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

Addition to @Venugopal`s answer. 
To display that loading image in the html

```
<div ng-show="showLoader"><!-- so this div containing img will be dislpayed only when the showLoader is equal to true-->
  <img src="source"> <!-- or any other spinner -->
</div>
```

Comment: sir i alredy did, images attached above question, pls see above images

Comment: what i want is, when display the loader , screen 1 image display code part did not show.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the loader image before the ajax call and remove it after it completes in both success and error handler.

you will find plenty of loader images online, which you can use it for your application.

**JS CODE**

```
 //show the loader image in center of screen & prevent any user interactions
 $scope.imLoading = true;
 $http.get('http://www.testurl.com/index.php/site/getprofileLocations').then(
   function(data){
       //hide the loader image & process successful data. 
       $scope.imLoading = false;    
   }, function (errorData) {
       //hide the loader image & show error message to user
       $scope.imLoading = false;
 });
```

**CSS:**

```
.im_loading{
 display:none;
 position:fixed;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin:-35px 0px 0px -35px;
 background:#fff url(../images/loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
 width:70px;
 height:70px;
 z-index:9999;
 -moz-border-radius:10px;
 -webkit-border-radius:10px;
 border-radius:10px;
 -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #000;
 box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #000;
 opacity:0.7;
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=70);
}
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="im_loading" ng-show:"imLoading"></div>
```

*Note: Your code is proccessing only successful ajax call & not erroneous call which is not good as your code becomes unresponsive when error is returned, so you need to handle error case as well.*

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing:

- Keep hidden your html content by default
- Show it when you get the response

like:

```
<div class="content" ng-show="!showLoader">
   .....
</div>
```

So using this only loader will show till you get your data from server.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we use an HTTP call in AngularJS, we want to show the loading image by default. So here, we are going to achieve this by using a custom directive.

**JS CODE**

```
var app = angular.module('appMyCustomModule',[]);
app.directive('dirCustomLoader', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="loading-icon"></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.isLoading = function () {
                return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
            };
            scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (value) {
                if (value) 
                    element.removeClass('ng-hide');
                else 
                    element.addClass('ng-hide');
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**CSS:**

```
.loading-icon {
    background: url(static image url) no-repeat scroll center #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999999999999999999 !important;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<dir-custom-loader class="ng-hide"></dir-custom-loader>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way that prevents showing two icons for example:

(BAD WAY)

When angular is manipulating the DOM, it can show the search icon before hiding the loading icon. Thats why its bad to have two elements.

```
<i class="fa fa-search" ng-hide="loadingData" ></i>
<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin" ng-show="loadingData"></i>
```

(GOOD WAY)

This way prevents showing the loading and the search icon when angular is hiding and showing elements.

```
<i class="fa" ng-class="loadingData ?  'fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin' : 'fa-search' " ></i>
```

And the script would be something like this.

```
$scope.clickEventThatDoSomething = function () {
    $scope.loadingData = true;
    http.get('http://YourAPIUrl').then(function (data) {
        $scope.loadingData = false;
        $scope.data = data.data;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        $scope.loadingData = false;
    })
}
```