# Hide elements before they rendered Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller displayedEntries has initilized from the ajax call and length is 3. When the page is load, it still shows the no data message before my table is filled. How could i hide this message before the displayed entries rendered with data.

```
<span class="h4"  ng-show="(displayedEntries | filter : { type : { name: type.name}}).length == 0">{{'public.TABLE_NO_DATA'|translate}}</span>
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866447/prevent-double-curly-brace-notation-from-displaying-momentarily-before-angular-j

Comment: How about `.h4{ display:none; }` in css ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a directive of angular-translate which help you to do this. `translate-cloak` this directive need to be included by another script tag. (supposely available in `src/directory` of `angular-translate`

your header

```
<script src="../src/directive/translate-cloak.js"></script>
```

your HTML

```
<span class="h4" translate-cloak  ng-show="(displayedEntries | filter : { type : { name: type.name}}).length == 0">{{'public.TABLE_NO_DATA'|translate}}</span>
```

your CSS

```
.translate-cloak {
     display: none !important;
}
```

**EDIT**: updated the answer
**EDIT2** : you can follow this [example](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/blob/master/demo/ex10_translate-cloak.html)

Comment: i already did this but not worked for this case. it still shows that span but after page refreshes.

Comment: I was made a mistake with the directive name `ng-cloak` . You can give it another try. ;)

Comment: @nolines, forgive I made another mistake. :(   by confusing with translate-cloak ---- I will rewrite my answer really quick

Comment: translate-cloak is worked as well. but it gives a little bit delay, too weird.

Comment: @nolines. it supposed to be like that. Since things got synchronized and only display after all the transate done. It is hard for the performance ofc. And also this is why the directive not implemented as default. ---- P.S. You can also try to remove that ```ng-show``` if it is not necessary.