# Binding expressions are being displayed while page is loading in angular js

Tags: angularjs, binding-expressions

I am creating blog site using Codeigniter and angular js but the problem is that the binding expression {{firstName}} is displayed while page loading.Is there any solution to fix it in angular js.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent double curly brace notation from displaying momentarily before angular.js compiles/interpolates document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866447/prevent-double-curly-brace-notation-from-displaying-momentarily-before-angular-j)

Comment: But this question has only issue of IE and for mine. it is for all browsers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ngCloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak) directive in the parts of your app where the curly brackets are getting showed