# how to set an initial value for getter in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have a getter to return a value that is calculated in another function. It has the form like this:

```
private get numErrors() {
    return calculateErrors(key);
}
```

In my html I have `{{ $ctrl.numErrors }}`. I am using AngularJS. This renders {{ $ctrl. numErrors }} for a few seconds before the value numerical value is calculated and displayed. Is there a way I can get it to initially display 0 before I get a return value?

Comment: See if it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866447/prevent-double-curly-brace-notation-from-displaying-momentarily-before-angular-j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially get around this via `ng-cloak`.

But instead of having `numErrors()` as a getter directly returning your other function's results why not do something like this? Have `calculateErrors()` get called in your logic where you need it to and have it set the value. This will be automatically updated on your template.

```
numErrors: number = 0;

calculateErrors(key) {
    // Do calculation
    numErrors = resultOfCalculation;
}
```

Comment: ng-cloak didn't completely solve the problem but for now I put it in a try catch block

Answer (score -1):

Considering that it is numeric value and it shouldn't be checked if it strictly equals to `undefined`, it can be

```
private get numErrors() {
    return calculateErrors(key) || 0;
}
```

Or

```
{{ $ctrl.numErrors || 0 }}
```

Comment: this does not work because the function doesn't return an error it just takes a while to process

Comment: The question and the answer - both of them - don't t say anything about errors. What is 'a while to process' supposed to mean? If it doesn't return a value immediately (i.e. the value is calculated and be available on the next digest), `0` is returned instead. The code in the question can't explain why it wouldn't work.