# How can I get rid of the curly bracket from angularjs output and to clear the screen after the display

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I thought I finally understand ng-repeat but now I do not know why the output include the curly bracket and how do I clear the screen after reading the output.
Here is part of the output

```
{"title":"NFL Draft 2020: Over 50 prospects will take part in 'virtual' interviews to air during the event, per report - CBS Sports"} 
{"title":"Illinois governor says feds sent wrong type of protective medical masks - CNN"}
```

but what I really want is just the following without the curly bracket, the word title and the double quotes.

```
NFL Draft 2020: Over 50 prospects will take part in 'virtual' interviews to air during the event, per report - CBS Sports
```

and after displaying the list of headlines, I want to clear the screen ( as in "cls" in the command prompt)
my angularjs code is this

```
   $http.post('/disdata', " ").then(function(response) {
    $scope.answer = response.data;
    var titles = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.answer.length; i++) {
    titles.push ({  
    title: $scope.answer[i].title 
    });
    };
    $scope.titles = titles;
    console.log($scope.titles);
```

My html is

```
   <div   ng-repeat="(key, value) in titles">    
    {{value}} 
    </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866447/prevent-double-curly-brace-notation-from-displaying-momentarily-before-angular-j i find something

Comment: I tried it before and it did not work for me. It clears the console (as in the development tool) but not the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you are using is usually used to iterate over properties in an object. Since you already have an array, you can normally iterate over it and display the `title` value.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', ($scope) => {
  $scope.titles = [{
      "title": "NFL Draft 2020: Over 50 prospects will take part in 'virtual' interviews to air during the event, per report - CBS Sports"
    },
    {
      "title": "Illinois governor says feds sent wrong type of protective medical masks - CNN"
    }
  ];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="title in titles">
    {{title.title}}
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: great. It works. Thank you. Now I need to figure out how to clear the window, i.e like "cls" in window . Is it even possible to use jquery?

Comment: I figure that out (or a work around). There are several functions for this app, hence I do not want the data to be on the screen. All I need is to set $scope.titles = " " to be the first line in the other options.